# I am looking for a cached copy of a website

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I am looking for a cached copy of a website (`www.shopthepackersgear.com`).

They have recently changed their website, and I would like to find a copy of their old one. When I use Google Cache it skips by the page then goes to google.com.

I only need the version from maybe 2 or 3 weeks back.  Is there some way to find this or did the people who own the site delete all evidence? I'm not sure what is possible these days and I need help.

Answer (score 2):

You can sometimes get old versions of a website at [The Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org), however, websites can block this. According to their logs, the site in question was crawled on 22 Jan 2013, although there does not seem to be anything recorded unfortunately (it might have been blocked).

Also check the cache at Bing and Yahoo!